# How to use Arduino 9 axes motion shield

Tags: arduino

I've just bought a brand new Uno rev3 and 9-axes-motion shield, however there doesn't seem to be any documentation or working examples :/

All the top search results seem to refer to a previous version of the code (where its referred to as `NAxisMotion` where as now its `NineAxesMotion`.

Regardless, I'm getting calibration states of `0` on all sensors using the example codes with the below library and from the few examples i can find traces of

Are there some pin differences, or interrupt values which are different to the defaults in the code?

https://github.com/arduino-org/arduino-library-nine-axes-motion

The internet seems completely barren on this shield :/

**Update to make example questions clear**

- What is the pin out/pin usage for the 9-axes-motion-shield?
- How can I determine if my I2C interface is "working" (sending/receiving data)
- Any other debug advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was difficult to solve.

The default pins specified inside NineAxesMotion.h are wrong for the way boards are configured.

See this PR: https://github.com/arduino-org/arduino-library-nine-axes-motion/pull/6

Look at your board and see how pins 4 or 2, and 3 or 7 are jumpered to the Interrupt and Reset pins respectively.

The defaults these days seem to be Interrupt = 2, Reset = 7.

I've updated the defaults in that PR and improved the comments and readme. If you don't want to use my PR, you need to hack NineAxesMotion.h and change the RESET_PIN and INT_PIN definitions to your pinout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you do web research but this is what I found within 1 minute:

https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/techmirtz/using-9-axes-motion-shield-with-arduino-e71107

https://hackaday.io/project/26925-using-9-axes-motion-shield-with-arduino

https://www.instructables.com/id/Using-9-Axes-Motion-Shield-With-Arduino/

and many other forum discussion. So I wouldn't agree that the Internet is barren on this shield.

There is also a full documentation on the Bosch IC for which this shield is basically just a breakout board for which Arduino provides the schematics.

https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/products/all_products/bno055

So what else can you wish for?

Comment: Either I've got a dud board, or none of that code works. Those 3 examples are all using an old version of the github library. Both updating them to use the current version or using an old version of the lib yield 0s in all calibration statues. No where does it talk about having to calibrate the board. I've watched all the Bosch videos on this, but their tooling doesnt interface directly with the arduino board as its a shield and not the standalone USB interfaced version.

Comment: Regardless, ive tried the various calibration incantations without success. Looking through the github code for the library it seems to have a number of either mistakes or misleading comments to do with interrupts, pins and I2c. Given its "not working" without erroring or giving any feedback, Arduino.cc barely seems to acknowledge its existence beyond the item in the store. Given the rest of the internet is truly so "barren" I am genuinely confused as to whats going on and/or how to use it. Or my boards broken

Comment: Does the adafruit version have any additional hardware on it? Or will be seemingly much more supported adafruit libraries work as just well with this board? Will give it a try

Comment: And with regard the schematics, they don't make a great deal of sense. I can't seriously be expected to reverse engineer a badly labelled pcb schematic and debug misleading/erroneous code to make this work?